# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react.proptypes.shape') - React Native

Tags: react-native

Working on a react native application. After the application is build successfully I get this error `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react.proptypes.shape')`

[image]

Searched for `_react.proptypes.shape` in my project directory returns no result for it. Also the latest version of prop-types package is installed.

[image]

I can't seem to figure out what is the issue here. Any suggestions from you guys that could help in resolving this issue or trace what is causing this. Looking forward to your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this type of issue while using testing one of my project. To resolve this issue, I simply removed "props-types" by executing command npm uninstall props-types. If you want to further assistance so please share your code because you have installed or import something that making conflict with props-types. you have latest props-type version that conflicted dependence may be deprecated or obsoleted. so kindly share your code for help then i may help you. Thanks

Comment: I have tried uninstalling "prop-types" plugin but this didn't had any effect on it and I was getting the same error. I am not sure which plugin is conflicting as the previous developer has used a lot of plugins.

Comment: this is issue happening due to stack navigation(react native version greater than 0.60), and its linking dependencies  because "react-navigation" switch to "react-native-stack" which making a lot of issues. sorry, with out-looking your code. I can't help you. Many of my friends are also facing such issues due to change of this library.

Comment: I have manage to fix this issue. In my case there was a plugin react-native-app-intro which was causing this issue it was quite outdated. I had to do some changes to it and it started working. I will be removing this plugin from the application in the future.